# Using PokeAPI to fetch data. Can't figure out why span element is not updating

Tags: javascript, html, api, fetch-api

So I'm using the PokeAPI to fetch the name of a Pokemon, then shuffling that name, and the user is supposed to guess what it is in the input. If they don't know then they can click the next button and it reshuffles a new mon. If they guess right they can press the same next button for a new mon. Each time they guess right the score increases by 1. That's working but I cant figure out why the out of/total games span isn't updating as well. Please excuse my terrible attempt at JS I'm very new if you can help me make my code look better that would be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>Who's that Pkmn?</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Who's that Pokemon?!</h1>
        </header>

      <div id="jumble">?????</div>

        <div class="container">
            <input id="guess" type="text" placeholder="enter pkmn name" />
            <button id="submit" class="btn" type="submit">go</button>
            <button id="next" class="btn">next</button>
        <p id="msg">unshuffle the letters</p>
    </div>


        <div id="scorekeepers">
            <p>Score: <span id="score">0</span>
            out of: <span id="gamesPlayed">0</span></p>
        </div>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
let jumbledName = document.querySelector("#jumble");
let guessInput = document.querySelector('#guess')
let submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit')
let nextButton=document.querySelector('#next')
let messageDisplay = document.querySelector('#msg')
let score = document.querySelector('#score')
let gamesPlayed = document.querySelector('#gamesPlayed')

score = 0;
gamesPlayed = 0;

let getPokemonName = function() {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${Math.floor(Math.random()*151+1)}/`)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            const pokeName = data.name;
            const pokeNameJumbled = pokeName.shuffle();
            displayInfomation(pokeName, pokeNameJumbled);
        });
};
getPokemonName();
guessInput.value=''
// pokeNameJumbled=''
const displayInfomation = function(name, jumbledName) {
    pokeName = name;
    pokeNameJumbled = jumbledName;
    jumble.textContent = jumbledName;
};
const displayMessage = function(message) {
    document.querySelector("#msg").textContent = message;
};

const checkName = function () {
    document.querySelector("#guess").textContent = guessInput;
    const guess = document.querySelector("#guess").value.toLowerCase();

    if (!guess) {
        displayMessage("No guess entered!");
    } else if (guess === pokeName) {
        displayMessage(`Thats correct! It's ${pokeName}!`)
        score++
        document.querySelector("#score").textContent = score;
        guessInput.value=''

    } else if (guess != pokeName) {
        displayMessage(`Wrong!`);
        document.querySelector("#gamesPlayed").textContent = gamesPlayed;
    }
};

submitButton.addEventListener('click', checkName)
nextButton.addEventListener('click',getPokemonName)

String.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var a = this.split(""),
        n = a.length;
    for (var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
    return a.join("");
};
```

Comment: Here it is so you can see it
https://codepen.io/a1d3nmam3d0v/pen/porWKxY

Comment: Haven't looked too close but `document.querySelector("#guess").textContent = guessInput` isn't going to work. Did you mean `guessInput.value`?

Comment: Yeah I believe so